# count sum of rows in multiple excel files using PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, count, sum, row

**PART 1)** I have **multiple** ***XLXS*** excel files saved in a folder path:

***File Name   Row count***
Excel 1     10
Excel 2     20
Excel 3     10
Excel 4     10
Excel 5     5

Each XLXS file contains the **SAME columns eg: Name, Postcode, Address, Number**

Each has a **different row count**:

I need a quick way to **COUNT and SUM** all the rows in these 5 Excel files on PYTHON. (I have done it manually and I have never used Python and need to do this on Python)

Desired output should be:

Total Count= 55

**PART 2)**
Now that I have the total count I need to COMPARE the count of the records to ensure they are the SAME in another seperate **** File (combined 5 xlxs files) -

it should both match to 55 rows

Comment: please provide information about the contents of the excel files and how they are differs

Answer (score 0):

This script should do what you want if the file extension is .csv, .tsv for example:

```
sm=0
for i in range(1,6):
  lines = len(open("Excel {}".format(i)).readlines())
  print("Lines for Excel {} = {}".format(i, lines))
  sm = sm + lines

print("Sum of all lines = {}".format(sm))
```

EDIT:
Since it's .xlsx files, you have to use `xlrd` library:

```
import xlrd

sm=0
for i in range(1,6):
  lines = xlrd.open_workbook("Excel {}".format(i)).sheet_by_index(0).nrows
  print("Lines for Excel {} = {}".format(i, lines))
  sm = sm + lines

print("Sum of all lines = {}".format(sm))
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this :) where should I add the file location? in between the brackets { } ?

Comment: You should add this script in the same directory/folder where those excel files stored. And just run it.

Comment: @Kasper have you tried above scripts, direct ``readlines`` may not work on excel files unless they are saved as csv files.

Comment: I see! How would I go about doing this if I just wanted the row count of one single file eg for Excel 1? not all of them

Comment: @Sushanth yh my files are saved as xlxs files would there be another way to do it maybe using pandas?

Comment: @Girl007, yes it is possible before that you will need to include some minimal reproducable example with expected output.

Comment: I edited the answer, it will work for .xlsx files now. I assumed it's a csv file at the beginning. Thank you @Sushanth

Comment: @Girl007 if you want to count the lines for just one file you can do this `lines = xlrd.open_workbook("Excel 1").sheet_by_index(0).nrows` for example to count Excel 1 lines

Comment: @Kasper thanks I didnt make it clear my bad!  I basically copied all the rows from the 5 xlsx files onto a CSV file. Is there a way I can COMPARE the count on both to make sure it adds up!

Comment: using this `csvlines = len(open("CSV-Excel {}".format(i)).readlines())` you can count csv file rows and by using this `lines = xlrd.open_workbook("Excel {}".format(i)).sheet_by_index(0).nrows` you can count .xlsx rows. So, you can in the same loop check like this `if lines == csvlines:` and do the logic you want in this if statement.

Comment: @kasper I see, I have 5 xlsx files and only 1 CSV file which combines all the 5 xlsx file contents

Comment: then you need to compare the `sm` for all .xlsx files with this `len(open("file.csv").readlines())` which is the count for the csv file